# How can we see the columns of an index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to see the columns of a specific index, but with no success and appreciate any help.

```
select * from sys.indexes 
inner join sys.index_columns on sys.indexes.object_id = sys.index_columns.object_id
inner join sys.columns on sys.index_columns.column_id = sys.columns.column_id 
where sys.indexes.name = 'IndexName'
```

Comment: [*`column_id` is unique only within `object_id`*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-index-columns-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: FYI 3+ part naming for columns is to be deprecated and should be avoided. Alias your objects and then qualify your columns with the alias instead.

Comment: You should also be joining sys.indexes and sys.index_columns using both object_id and index_id; and sys.index_columns and sys.columns using both object_id and column_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarized all the comments in an answer.

**Sample data**

```
create table MyTable
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 int,
  Col3 int
);

create clustered index MyIdx1 on MyTable (Col1);

create nonclustered index MyIdx2 on MyTable (Col2);

create nonclustered index MyIdx3 on MyTable (Col2) include (Col3);
```

**Solution**

```
select i.object_id as table_id,
       object_name(i.object_id) as table_name,
       i.index_id,
       i.name as index_name,
       i.type_desc as index_type,
       c.column_id,
       c.name as column_name,
       ic.is_included_column as column_included
from sys.indexes i
join sys.index_columns ic
  on  ic.object_id = i.object_id
  and ic.index_id = i.index_id
join sys.columns c
  on  c.object_id = ic.object_id
  and c.column_id = ic.column_id
where i.name like 'MyIdx%';
```

**Result**

```
table_id    table_name  index_id    index_name      index_type      column_id   column_name column_included
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------- --------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------
581577110   MyTable     1           MyIdx1          CLUSTERED       1           Col1        False
581577110   MyTable     2           MyIdx2          NONCLUSTERED    2           Col2        False
581577110   MyTable     3           MyIdx3          NONCLUSTERED    2           Col2        False
581577110   MyTable     3           MyIdx3          NONCLUSTERED    3           Col3        True
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4f91e8ec9162ef18d9ff06a2cff34bd5)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.